# Inserting HTML code without being affected by CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to insert some HTML code inside a page, the code I insert should not be affected by the CSS and JS of that page, it should load it's own CSS and JS.

Example Code:

```
<div class="body">
  <p>Example Content </p>
  <p>Sample Content 2 </p>
  <div class="special-div">
      <p> No CSS and JS to be applied to this div 'special-div', it should load it's own CSS and JS </p>
  </div><!-- /.special-div -->
</div><!-- /.body -->
```

In the above code div with class "special-div" should load it's own CSS and JS and should not be affected by page's CSS and JS

I've tried using iframes but firstly they are cross origin, secondly iframe has it's own scroll bar.

I am trying to insert a slider into wordpress page, I've built slider in a HTML site and tested it but the default wordpress styles and JS are changing the layout. I can easily remove the styles but I'm not sure how to get rid of the JS which is affecting the slider

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: In terms of the css you can write rules that all begin with .special-div { // params here } etc. so .special-div p, .special-div h1 etc. But you would need to load a script inside that block of html that is being inserted. And this would not be standalone to the rest of the page. It depends on what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Sounds like a case for the [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

Comment: As for the iframe having a scrollbar you can get around that, but you have to use a set height, or calculate the height of the content of the iframe if you know it.

Comment: I am trying to insert a slider into wordpress page, I've built slider in a HTML site and tested it but the default wordpress styles and JS are changing the layout. I can easily remove the styles but I'm not sure how to get rid of the JS which is affecting the slider

Comment: In that case it should just be an issue of updating the target selector for your slider. I think anyway. Maybe we need an example.

Comment: Okay, I'll add an example link shortly. Thank you for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM).

> Shadow DOM provides encapsulation for the JavaScript, CSS and templating in a Web Component. Shadow DOM makes it so these things remain separate from the DOM of the main document. You can also use Shadow DOM by itself, outside of a web component.